# How to know the labels assigned by astype('category').cat.codes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I have the following dataframe called `language`

```
         lang          level
0      english         intermediate
1      spanish         intermediate
2      spanish         basic
3      english         basic
4      english         advanced
5      spanish         intermediate
6      spanish         basic
7      spanish         advanced
```

I categorized each of my variables into numbers by using

`language.lang.astype('category').cat.codes`

and

`language.level.astype('category').cat.codes`

respectively. Obtaining the following data frame:

```
      lang   level
0      0       1
1      1       1
2      1       0
3      0       0
4      0       2
5      1       1
6      1       0
7      1       2
```

Now, I would like to know if there is a way to obtain which original value corresponds to each value. I'd like to know that the `0` value in the `lang` column corresponds to english and so on.

Is there any function that allows me to get back this information?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can generate dictionary:

```
c = language.lang.astype('category')

d = dict(enumerate(c.cat.categories))
print (d)
{0: 'english', 1: 'spanish'}
```

So then if necessary is possible `map`:

```
language['code'] = language.lang.astype('category').cat.codes

language['level_back'] = language['code'].map(d)
print (language)
      lang         level  code level_back
0  english  intermediate     0    english
1  spanish  intermediate     1    spanish
2  spanish         basic     1    spanish
3  english         basic     0    english
4  english      advanced     0    english
5  spanish  intermediate     1    spanish
6  spanish         basic     1    spanish
7  spanish      advanced     1    spanish
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use .cat.categories index, like this:

```
df.lang.cat.categories[0]
```

Output:

```
'english'
```

Answer (score 7):

The categorical type is a process of factorization.  Meaning that each unique value or category is given a incremented integer value starting from zero.

For example:

```
c = language.lang.astype('category')
```

You've got codes in

```
codes = c.cat.codes
```

And categories in

```
cats = c.cat.categories
```

It is designed to enable you to leverage Numpy array slicing and you can get access to your labels or categories via

```
cats[codes]

Index(['english', 'spanish', 'spanish', 'english', 'english', 'spanish',
       'spanish', 'spanish'],
      dtype='object')
```

There is no need to construct a dictionary to look it up when you are already given a construct to look it up quite efficiently.

---

As further example, this is how we can replicate with `pd.factorize`

```
codes, cats = pd.factorize(language.lang)

print(cats, codes, cats[codes], sep='\n\n')

Index(['english', 'spanish'], dtype='object')

[0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1]

Index(['english', 'spanish', 'spanish', 'english', 'english', 'spanish',
       'spanish', 'spanish'],
      dtype='object')
```