# number of units of the output layer（ softmax） and the number of labels in the data do not match?

Tags: deep-learning

I encountered the following problems when training a deep learning model with data. As a novice, I didn't find a suitable answer. I hope you guys can help me out! ! Thank you very much!

[image]For the first image, I extracted 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 14, 18 from the dataset (there are 20 labels) as labels. Normally, I only need to enter 10 in the softmax layer and the model will function properly; the error shows that we need to set the number of units in the softmax layer to 19 for the model to function properly, and this is exactly what happened.[image]For the second picture, I only changed the last labels to 16, then we need to set the number of units in the softmax to 17 for the model to function properly.
[image]
[image]
So why does the number of units of the output layer(softmax) and the number of labels in the data do not match!!
Although I can change the number of units in the softmax layer to make the model work properly, I'm not sure if this has an impact on the accuracy of the model！

Comment: The classes are named from 0 to the maximum number, in your case you have 18 as maximum, so 19 classes total. Rename the classes from [1,2,4,5,6,7,12,14,18] to [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: For example, you could add line `train_data1['faultNumber'] = train_data1['faultNumber'].astype("category").cat.codes`

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Thank you for your answer, It's give me lots of help!!  Could you set the comment as an answer, I wanna accepted it！！！！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of classes is determined from the maximum label number, that appears in your data. In your case since the maximum label was 18, you would have classes 0, 1, 2, ..., 18, so 19 classes in total (exactly as specified in the error).

To solve it, you need to remap the classes labels `[1,2,4,5,6,7,12,14,18]` to `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`. It can be done manually using a dictionary, or automatically, e.g. this could work:

```
train_data1['faultNumber'] = train_data1['faultNumber'].astype("category").cat.codes
```

The original labels could be then recovered from `train_data1['faultNumber']` using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51102402/8564999), because it has now `category` type.